# Getting "404 not found" on doing a GET on local file in Azure web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a simple node based web app in Azure. Following is the structure of my code:

[image: Code structure]

In my js code, when I do an `xhr.get` call to my json file (as shown below), it throws a `GET https://<app-url>/locales/en-US.json 404 (Not Found)`.

```
    xhr.open("GET", "locales/en-us.json", true);
    ...
    xhr.send();
```

As seen below, the calls to my js file and css file are succeeding but the call to my locale file is failing. External calls are working fine too. **Note**: js and css files have been included as part `script` tag and `link` tags respectively in my `index.html` file.

[image]

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common issue of Azure Website which be lack of the `mimetype` setting for static json file, please refer to the [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/africaapps/2013/06/07/how-to-serve-static-json-files-from-a-windows-azure-website/). You just need to add the configurate below into your `web.config` file under `wwwroot`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then it works via your browser.