# how enable permission on assets folder

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

i deploy my project on web app(angular 7 with angular cli) azure and i can see it "working" on my site.
the problem is that it seems the app can't access the assets folder, all the request fail.

```
e {headers: t, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "https://<mysite>/assets/i18n/it.json", ok: false, …}
error: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
headers: t {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for https://<mysite>/assets/i18n/it.json: 404 Not Found"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "https://<mysite>/assets/i18n/it.json"
```

what i have change is the virtual path from

```
site\wwwroot
```

to

```
site\wwwroot\dist\<name of project>
```

adding the following setting:

```
"WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" "8.10.0" 
"SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT" "1800"
```

the folder is present if i navigate there with console but if i navigate in it via browser the response is :

> "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

the file too is present but instead give me the error:

> "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

i even try adding the assets folder as directory in the "Virtual applications and directories":

```
VIRTUAL PATH    PHYSICAL PATH                             TYPE  
/               site\wwwroot\dist\mysite               Application  
/assets         site\wwwroot\dist\mysite\assets        Directory
```

but it didn't change anything

can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a common issue of Azure WebApp, which default not support for static json files. To fix it, you need to add a `mimetype` setting for json to `web.conf`. Please refer to my answer for the other similar SO thread [Getting "404 not found" on doing a GET on local file in Azure web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967169/getting-404-not-found-on-doing-a-get-on-local-file-in-azure-web-app/53984058#53984058).

Here is the sample `mimetype` setting for `web.conf`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: where should i put it? in the src folder and build the application or in the dist folder after i build?

Comment: @Phoenix5650 The `web.config` file should be in the `wwwroot` folder. If there is not an existing one, you just need to create it by yourself.

Comment: even if i change my virtual path in the dist folder?

Comment: @Phoenix5650 Yeah, it is configured for IIS.