# How to recognize a JSON format in APP Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We’re building a web app (aspcore 3.0) published in app service.
This problem is that the mine type (json) is not recognized. 
How to fix it ?
Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by not recognized?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you were using Azure App Service on Windows to deploy your ASP.NET Core 3.0 application, but IIS on Azure WebApp can not set the response header `Content-Type` for JSON.

The reason is IIS on Azure WebApp default does not support static JSON file. To fix it, you need to change the `web.config` file to add the feature, as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

As reference, there is the other SO thread [Getting "404 not found" on doing a GET on local file in Azure web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967169/getting-404-not-found-on-doing-a-get-on-local-file-in-azure-web-app/53984058#53984058) got the similar issue as yours and I answered it, please refer to it.